# What is the best way to store user generated conditions and consistently check them?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, web-applications

An application keeps track of hundreds of variables. Users are able to create conditions which can be simple (ex: if one variable is true) or complex (ex: if 34 variables are true AND 22 variables are false AND 2 variables are equal to each other). If the condition ever becomes true, it fires off some action. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the run-time environment (what language, what O/S, and how/where/in what format are the conditions stored)? What do you mean by 'best' way (do you mean easiest to program, least CPU time, ...)? And what's wrong with whatever the most obvious way of doing it is?

Comment: PHP, Linux. I was hoping the answer to this question would be independent of this though. Condition storage is what I am looking to gather more information about - what is the best practice for a situation like this? And when you say, "what's wrong with whatever the most obvious way of doing it" - what is the most obvious way you are implying?

Comment: The most obvious way is like:

1) Create condition instances. The implementation of each condition instance is an exercise for the reader, but every condition instance supports the same API, e.g. a function named `test()` which evaluates the condition and returns a boolean result.

2) Store all these instances somewhere, e.g. on some list or array or whatever your generic collection type is.

3) Periodically, iterate over the list: for each condition instance, evaluate it by invokng its `test()` method, and fire off some action if the test returns `true`.

Comment: And as for 'best', let's say the easier way to program unless an exorbitant amount of performance is sacrificed in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for in general is a [business rules engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) (BRE).  There are [lots](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/top-10-java-business-rule-engines/) of lightweight and more [heavy BREs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430723.aspx) out there.  Depending on your specific needs, you should be able to find one that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The post by JP on BREs seems to be the way to go. 
Drupal CMS is implementing a Rules engine, http://drupal.org/project/rules
http://groups.drupal.org/node/10270

It may help with your situation since you need a solution in PHP.